# Unfortunately Google Play Services stopped won't go away

Tags: google-play-services

A pop-up that says 'Unfortunately, Google Play services stopped' won't go away on my phone. Everything I've read says to go to settings and then apps but I physically can't, the pop up doesn't go away when I tap the Ok button, it just flickers a little. When I go into settings I can't do anything because the pop up basically shuts down the whole screen and I can't open anything. Is there anything at all I can do to fix this, or is my phone just permanently broken because of this?

Comment: In the tag you used, there are a [bunch of questions] (https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-play-services%5D+stopped) with the same problem and solutions. Go through them and see if your problem can be solved. If solved, please revert with the question that helped so that your question can be marked as duplicate. If not, [edit] question to say what you tried and what happened

Comment: I did go through them, and I already said what happened. None of it works because I physically cannot get to the settings people said to change.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Phone can't be used anyway, so try and take a backup of important stuff if possible and factory reset the device (giggle how to factory reset your device)